# Convert date to specific format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a  column with values as below .Data type is 'Text'

```
 Check-in

 26Nov2017
 09Jun2017
 19Jan2018
```

I am trying to convert into specific format

```
Check-in

Nov-17
Jun-17
Jan-18
```

I am getting type explicit error when i try writing as

```
 select Check-in,to_date(Check-in,'Mon-YY') as Check-in_updated from my_table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert it into date explicitly using `CAST()`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=89646cfd0567c4910e008e0bb183279e)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(cast(Check-in as date), 'Mon-YY')
```

Output:

```
Nov-17
```